# Sliding Tab/menu within ionic template

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to insert 'sliding tabs' within a tabs starter.  Basically I'm wanting to use the 'starter' tabs at the bottom, but within one of those tabs (template pages) I want to have a sliding menu (https://github.com/leoruhland/ion-slides-tabs).  I've tried what I know and can't seem to figure out how to make it work.  Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: You haven't shown what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

For simple Ionic slider you can refer from this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/ and for other your sample INstallation is already showing .You can use that directive and can work. I am also using this in my Project.